# jQuery condition is true, but it's not committing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a simple form that I send to the server and I'm using jQuery ajax.

If everything on the server goes well - it'll respond with "OK".

if not, a detailed error.

This is my jQuery request:

```
        $("#addnewcouponbtn").click(function() {
            var texts = $("#addCouponForm .modal-body input");
            var bid = texts[0].value;
            var image = texts[1].value;
            var date = texts[2].value;
            var time = texts[3].value;
            var details = $("#addCouponForm .modal-body textarea").val();
            $.post("system/addnewcoupon.jsp",
                    {bid: bid, image: image, details: details, date: date, time: time}, function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        if(data == "OK")
                            $("#addCouponForm").modal("hide");
                        else
                            alert(An error occourd! " + data);
            });
        });
```

Here's my addnewcoupon.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="entities.Coupon"%>
<%@page import="implementations.Coupons"%>
<%@page import="implementations.Businesses"%>
<%
    String bid = request.getParameter("bid");
    String image = request.getParameter("image");
    String details = request.getParameter("details");
    String date = request.getParameter("date");
    String time = request.getParameter("time");

    Businesses bm = Businesses.getInstance();
    if(bid == null || image == null || details == null || date == null || time == null) {
        out.println("Please specify all arguments!");
        return;
    }

    int id = Integer.parseInt(bid);
    if(!bm.isExist(id)) {
        out.println("No such business ID");
        return;
    } else {
        Coupons master = Coupons.getInstance();
        int insertId = master.getLastId() + 1;
        Coupon c = new Coupon(insertId, id, image, details, date, time);
        master.addCoupon(c);
        out.println("OK");
    }
%>
```

The problem is:

Even if "data" is "OK", jquery doesn't go to the condition,

it prints `An error occourd! OK`. (data = "OK")

What is the problem here?

Comment: The code shouldn't even run.. `else
                            alert(An error occourd! " + data);` is invalid in several ways.

Comment: @m59 Why is that code wrong?

Comment: `else { alert("An error occurred! " + data); }` The brackets *can* be skipped but probably shouldn't be on multiple lines. The string quotes are necessary.

Comment: Use text with quotes and variables without

Comment: @PiotrWójcik What do you mean? what is wrong here? `                    `if(data == "OK")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
out.println("OK");
```

with

```
out.print("OK");
```

You should know that println() adds a new line feed. "OK\n" will not be equal to "OK".